# Cassandra database schema and select IN issue

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have following database schema

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_info_table 
(
  asset_id text,
  event_time timestamp,
  "timestamp" timeuuid,
  sensor_reading map<text, text>,
  sensor_serial_number text,
  sensor_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((asset_id), event_time, "timestamp")
);

CREATE INDEX event_time_index ON sensor_info_table (event_time);

CREATE INDEX timestamp_index ON sensor_info_table ("timestamp");
```

Now I am able to insert the data into this table however I am unable to do following query where I want to select items with specific timeuuid values. It gives me following error.

```
SELECT * from mydb.sensor_info_table where timestamp IN ( bfdfa614-3166-11e4-a61d-b888e30f5d17 , bf4521ac-3166-11e4-87a3-b888e30f5d17) ;
```

> Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY column "timestamp" cannot be restricted (preceding column "event_time" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)

What do I have to do to make this work? Below is software version info.

show VERSION ;

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.9 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

I really don't understand what the error message preceding column "event_time" is either not restricted or by no-EQ relation?

-Subodh

Comment: Do this changes and check
PRIMARY KEY ((asset_id, event_time), "timestamp")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it work like this. `IN` predicate on lookup indexed columns is not supported.
So you won't be able to use `IN` on "timestamp" column. You could use `IN` if you also provide both asset_id and event_time -- that's what cqlsh is telling you with the message

> Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY column "timestamp" cannot be restricted
>   (preceding column "event_time" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ
>   relation)

The solution for your problem is denormalization. What happens under the hood when creating a  index is that Cassandra will create and handle for you a new table having the indexed as partition key -- so Cassandra has already denormalized and duplicated your data. Remove your index and create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_info_table_by_timestamp
(
  asset_id text,
  event_time timestamp,
  "timestamp" timeuuid,
  sensor_reading map<text, text>,
  sensor_serial_number text,
  sensor_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp", asset_id, event_time )
);
```

Now anytime you write data you put in both tables (you can use a batch).
And your query will be

```
SELECT * from mydb.sensor_info_table_by_timestamp where timestamp IN ( bfdfa614-3166-11e4-a61d-b888e30f5d17 , bf4521ac-3166-11e4-87a3-b888e30f5d17) ;
```

I see you also created a lookup index on event_time -- if you have to perform query using `IN` predicate you will have to create a third table ...

HTH,
Carlo

Answer (score 1):

[ I had posted this query on cassandra users mailing list, and as per suggestion I ended up creating two tables to handle this requirement ]

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_asset (
  asset_id text,
  event_time timestamp,
  tuuid timeuuid,
  sensor_reading map<text, text>,
  sensor_serial_number text,
  sensor_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((asset_id), event_time)
);

CREATE TABLE sensor_tuuid (
  asset_id text,
  event_time timestamp,
  tuuid timeuuid,
  sensor_reading map<text, text>,
  sensor_serial_number text,
  sensor_type int,
  PRIMARY KEY (tuuid)
);
```